# [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: invalid expression: Unexpected token >

Tags: laravel, vue.js, compiler-errors, vue-component

I got this error when I try to compile a Laravel-Page with only one Vue.js Component.

What I've figured out is, that the error have to be something with this line or what it returns:

```
<a href="{{route('sites.showSnippet', $snippet->id)}}">
              <pre><code class="language-{{isset($langs[0]) ? $langs[0]->language_name : ''}}">{{$snippet->short_snippet}}</code></pre> 
            </a>
```

Once I delete $snippet->short_snippet it works with no problems.

in the IMG you can see what it returns [image]

and here is the complete error log:

```
app.js:17685 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token > in

    "<p><a href=\""+_s(route('searchTag', $tags))+"\" title=\"search for "+_s($tags)+"\"> "+_s($tags)+"</a></p>\n\t\t@endif\n\t</div>\n\t@endif\n\t<copy snippetid=\""+_s($snippet->id)+"\"></copy>\n\t<div class=\"tooltip tooltip_views\">\n      <span class=\"tooltiptext\">Views</span>\n    <"

  Raw expression: <p><a href="{{route('searchTag', $tags)}}" title="search for {{$tags}}"> {{$tags}}</a></p>
        @endif
    </div>
    @endif
    <copy snippetid="{{$snippet->id}}"></copy>
    <div class="tooltip tooltip_views">
      <span class="tooltiptext">Views</span>
    <


91 |            <small>test@test.com, 2019-07-17</small>
92 |              <a href="http://codesnippet.local/snippet/3">
93 |                <pre><code class="language-">&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="{{route('searchTag', $tags)}}" title="search for {{$tags}}"&gt; {{$tags}}&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
94 |        @endif
   |  ^^^^^^^^
95 |    &lt;/div&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
96 |    @endif
   |  ^^^^^^^
97 |    &lt;copy snippetid="{{$snippet-&gt;id}}"&gt;&lt;/copy&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
98 |    &lt;div class="tooltip tooltip_views"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
99 |        &lt;span class="tooltiptext"&gt;Views&lt;/span&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
100|      &lt;</code></pre> 
   |  ^^^^^^^^

(found in <Root>)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: i understood that vuejs trys to compile the code from the pre code. As long as the $snippet->short_snippet has Code inside vue trys to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You short_snippet is getting HTML escaped.  Use the `v-html` directive instead.

Something like this:

```html
<code 
 class="language-{{isset($langs[0]) ? $langs[0]->language_name : ''}}" 
 v-html='$snippet->short_snippet'
>
</code>
```

You may have to try an alternate quote escaping in the `v-html` block, but hopefully you get the general idea.